# How to mark code snippet in Headerdoc?

Tags: code-snippets, headerdoc

I usually need to write many short code in code comment like `this`. Is this possible to use in Apple's *Headerdoc*? Because this type of code notation is generally used heavily, so i believe there's a convenient way to do this instead of marking HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with using `@c`.

```
This is an example @c code-style text.
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to format a block of code use: `@code` &`@endcode` tags like:

```
/**
 * @code
 * [myObj myMethod];
 * @endcode
 */
```

If you want to format a single word `@c` is enough, like:

```
/**
 * @c is enough
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

Within your HeaderDoc, you can use this formatting:

```
 @code
// code text
while (someCondition) {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    doSomething();
}@endcode
 Last line text.
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169271/1736056

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: `Unknown field type @code in HeaderDoc comment.`

Answer (score 1):

`@code` and `@c` don't seem to work as of Headerdoc 8.9.
I ended up using:

```
<pre>@textblock
@/textblock</pre>
```

Comment: For whom seeking for the right answer. This your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Xcode 6.4/HeaderDoc 8.9 and neither `@code` nor `@c` work. `<pre>code</pre>` works but adds newlines.

I ended up being able to produce inline code snippets by using `<tt>code</tt>` (teletype text).