# How to make a newline in parameter description of function documentation in XCode5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have read this question [`What are the new documentation commands available in Xcode 5?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168423/what-are-the-new-documentation-commands-available-in-xcode-5). And I have leaned that `\n: doesn't generate a newline. One way to create a newline is by making sure nothing is on that line. Not even a single space character!`. But this can only work in function description section, not in parameter description section.

My question is how can I achieve the effects like Apple's documentation as below:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found same new line in Array documentation. And Looks like it works only if parameter is block. Here is sample from Apple

```
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - unsafeUninitializedCapacity: The number of elements to allocate
    ///     space for in the new array.
    ///   - initializer: A closure that initializes elements and sets the count
    ///     of the new array.
    ///     - Parameters:
    ///       - buffer: A buffer covering uninitialized memory with room for the
    ///         specified number of elements.
    ///       - initializedCount: The count of initialized elements in the array,
    ///         which begins as zero. Set `initializedCount` to the number of
    ///         elements you initialize.
    @inlinable public init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: Int, initializingWith initializer: (_ buffer: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>, _ initializedCount: inout Int) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

[Link](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/24a1d011d87d3f733105d09d4e3f1c67987aba08/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L1544) to opensourced corelib, with same comments