# Appledoc inline code in Xcode Quick Help panel?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1, appledoc

How can I indicate **inline code blocks** like `this` in Appledoc comments?

Backticks just read as backticks in Xcode Quick Help panel.

[image]

I'd really love to have `NSStringFromClass` codified somehow.

Comment: So you couldn't be bothered to google "appledoc syntax"? You had to get someone to _tell_ you how to do it?

Comment: @msk `This entire comment is an inline code block. He's not referring to a website, he's referring to the code block.`

Comment: @matt The question emphasizes **xCode Quick Help panel**, I could not find any resources regarding this issue out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `@p` before a word to place it in monospaced font.

```
///
/// @summary does some stuff
///
/// Alias for @p NSStringFromClass actually.
///
```

[image: Code preview]

[Here's a pretty solid overview of available features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169271/143913).

Answer (score 1):

Start the code block with a tab character.

Comment: I meant **inline code**. Code blocks can be done by `@code` directive, which is fine.