# @availability keyword not working in Xcode "alt+click" documentation helper

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation, xcode5

I'm trying to document my header files and I really like the concept of alt+click documentation helper.
Using code below I can set keywords like `@param` or `@return` or `@see` but unforunately `@availability` is not being displayed in the proper way.

```
/**
 * Super method for super feature
 *
 * @param someParameter super cool method parameter
 *
 * @availability Version 3.0 (and later)
 *
 * @return void
 */
```

[image: availability problem]

The question is: how to set availability parameter in documentation helper?

Comment: Did you clean & re-build ?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Clean & re-build does not help.
@GuyKogus: edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `@since`, not `@availability`.

For a comprehensive list of commands, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168423/what-are-the-new-documentation-commands-available-in-xcode-5).

Answer (score 0):

You need to user `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0)` to show the availability. 
Here is an example:

```
/**
 Check whether a file at a given URL has a newer timestamp than a given file.
 Example usage:
 @code
 NSURL *url1, *url2;
 BOOL isNewer = [FileUtils
 isThisFileNewerThanThatFile:url1 thatURL:url2];
 @endcode
 @param index
 The index
 @return the results
 */
- (UIImage*)imageForSectionIndex:(NSUInteger)index NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0){
   // your implem
}
```