# Cross reference in XCode comments

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, doxygen

what I'm trying to do is to create comment with link to another method for example like in Doxygen

```
/**
 * Some comment {@link method}
 */
```

But when I do this comment in XCode it does not show links to methods in right QuickHelp panel.
Is there some quick explanation of how to do this or why I cannot do this?

I want to generate something like this, where in this example you can click CGImageRef or CIImage.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe link is supported.

Comment: Is there any alternative that is supported?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  See this (very) informative SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168423/what-are-the-new-documentation-commands-available-in-xcode-5

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at the link right now! There are methods with comments with links (see screenshot added)

Comment: And what does the related comment look like in `UIImage.h`?

Comment: There is not such comment in UIImage.h :D

Comment: Exactly; Apple use appledoc to generate their documents, don't they, not doc comments.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation so to achieve this functionality I must use appledoc

Comment: Yes, although it's not that simple as the generated documentation has to be installed into Xcode (look at how cocos2d do it), so it's not suitable for code you are currently developing.