# Make XCode's documentation command span multiple words?

Tags: xcode, documentation, comments, doxygen

A lot of the new documentation commands for XCode has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168423/what-are-the-new-documentation-commands-available-in-xcode-5), but even with the commands explained there, I can't seem to find a way to make a command span multiple words.

Let me give an example:

**Input:**
`Hi, I am for @a cosmetic purposes only.`

**Output:** Hi, I am for *cosmetic* purposes only.

Nothing wrong there, but imagine me wanting to make the word *purposes* italic as well. There the problem starts. I tried:

**Input:**
`Hi, I am for @a cosmetic @a purposes only.`

**Output:** Hi, I am for *cosmeticpurposes* only.

--

**Input:**
`Hi, I am for @a cosmetic <any amount of spaces> @a purposes only.`

**Output:** Hi, I am for *cosmeticpurposes* only.

--

**Input:**
`Hi, I am for @a cosmetic @a  @a purposes only.`

**Output:** Hi, I am for *cosmeticpurposes* only.

--

**Input:**
`Hi, I am for @a cosmetic @a  @a  @a purposes only.`

**Output:** Hi, I am for *cosmeticpurposes* only.

--

**Input:**
`Hi, I am for @a cosmetic <line break>
@a purposes only.`

**Output:** Hi, I am for *cosmeticpurposes* only.

--

As you can see, I can't seem to find a way to do it. Somehow all whitespaces seem to get trimmed. Does anyone knows a solution to this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already knew this or not but the following works for XCode 6:

*Italic:*

```
Hi, I am for <em>cosmetic purposes</em> only.
```

**Bold:**

```
Hi I am for <b>cosmetic purposes</b> only.
```

I am currently looking for a solution to `@c`, couldn't find one yet.

Edit: Oh well, `<code>...</code>` works for `@c`.

Comment: By the way, try out HTML tags, most of them works! You might be surprised with `<li>`, `<pre>` etc.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried a lot of HTML..indeed surprising how that just works. Makes documenting your code that much better!

Comment: `<a></a>` works in the way that if underlines and colours it like a link but it doesn't open the url :(. Maybe could someone tweak it to make it work, or even better, to redirect to another method like Apple own documentation does.

Comment: I guess you can make it work using a `href` attribute but you need to generate a docset to be able to follow links as you do in Apple's docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can put space in following way:

```
/*! Sample @a italic &#x200B; @a comment  */
```

just putting blank space code in between two tags

Comment: This still doesn't make the code span multiple words but, it is a nice workaround though. Until there is some way to really solve it, I'll use it.

Comment: you can try other special character code too :http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/SpecialChars.html, many of them may work for you

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the usage of character codes in the documentation. But I was hoping for a 'true' way to make a span in documentation (i.e. the <span> tag in HTML).

Comment: I dont think there may be such things available for documentation, still not sure

Comment: Hm. Since Xcode6 and Swift were coming, I was secretly hoping for them to add new documentation commands as well. Alas, nothing yet.
Currently scanning Apple-docs if they _do_ use a span or something.

Comment: Will tell you if i get it anywhere