# How to copy the objective-c method name more effecively in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return items.count;
}
```

What I do now is to copy the whole first line and then remove the words about the formal parameters. Is there a better way to copy the method name so that I can get `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` quickly?

Comment: Xcode autocomplete in Swift is probably the fastest way instead of copy pasting obj-c.

Comment: Yes, autocomplete is a effective way in writing code.  The reason I want to copy the method name is that I am documenting something where I have to list the method name.

Comment: If you want to document your class hierarchy consider the native markup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19168423/1271826. Then you have documentation right in Xcode. And if you use appledoc, you can generate external HTML documentation from this, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems not very nice, but you can right-click on method name, then `Refactor -> Rename` and `Cmd+C` to copy method name.

For even better access you can set the shortcut for this in `Xcode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings -> Rename`. That will require one click on method name and two shortcuts for getting signature

Comment: thanks for the answer. Anyway two shortcuts are more quick than the copy + paste + remove.

Comment: There's an even easier method: You can right-click on any part of method name, and choose "Find Selected Symbol in Workspace". The whole name will appear in the search field.

Answer (score 30):

In Xcode 7.3 and above you can simply do the following:

Given a class `ReportsListViewController` and the `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method:

#### To "Copy Qualified Symbol Name"

Place your cursor anywhere on a method name. Press Shift-Cmd-Ctrl-Option-c (All the modifiers) - This will place the following in your clipboard:

```
-[ReportsListViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]
```

#### To "Copy Symbol Name"

Place your cursor anywhere on a method name. Press Shift-Cmd-Ctrl-c - This will place the following in your clipboard:

```
-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

Comment: Considering when [this tweet](https://twitter.com/joar_at_work/status/765293744736260096) was posted, it's probably available earlier (likely Xcode 7).

Comment: Thank you very much, this should the shortcuts what I want. Thi should be the answer. Sorry I cannot mark it as I have marked another one. Thanks again.

Comment: Both of the 2 ways also work with the latest Xcode and swift 3. E.g, I copied this method: webView(_:shouldStartLoadWith:navigationType:).

Comment: glad I bothered to google this again (back to Objective-C, long story), thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Xcode's code snippet library.
In Xcode,View->Show Code Snippets Library
Select the code ,Long press on it，then you can find it being dragging,put it in the code snippet library,name an other name,such as “tns”