# Xcode not formatting document comment properly for Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-documentation

I added the following comment with backtick for code:

```
/** Checks if the given data is of type `list`. */
+ (BOOL)isList:(id)object {
    // ..
}
```

but the backtick prints as in the Xcode quick help:

[image]

How to get Xcode to display code formatted properly? It works fine when documenting Swift source.

Comment: try using `@p` or `@c` this post is a bit old, but still has a bunch of useful options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169271/7833793 alternatively if you're trying to do a larger code block using @code // @endcode

Comment: So you’re saying Swift uses markdown but Objective C doesn’t. What an odd thing for Apple to do.

Comment: Sure enough, `/// Checks if the given data is of type @c list.` works. Weird.

Comment: @R4N Maybe post your comment as an answer, including pointing out that for Objective-C code, you use the Objective-C style, and for Swift you use the markdown style.

Comment: @Kalle Added an answer, thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, in Objective-C documentation comments you can use `@p` or `@c` to display Typewriter font in the QuickHelp documentation. Whereas Swift documentation comments accept Markdown (using the backticks)

While this answers is relatively old, it still lists a good amount of the options available in Objective-C documentation comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19169271/7833793

Here's a brief example:

```
/// Here's how to use @c Typewriter @c Font
- (void)myMethod {}
```

Which displays this in the QuickHelp:
[image]