# Xcode 11 comments formatting

Tags: xcode

I am looking for pretty simple functionality how to format my comments (basically for internal documentation). Before f.e. for text bolding two asterisks from for sides would work, for italic text single quotes would work (``). Now it seems that they changed it and I can't find the documentation for it. Does anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future adventurers, this is the answer for my question: [What are the new documentation commands available in Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168423/what-are-the-new-documentation-commands-available-in-xcode-5)
it includes: `@b`for bold text, `@a` for italic and etc.

Comment: Update: it seems not to work so well with Swift. I've found out that two asterisks (**) before and after word bolds it, haven't figured out other formatting yet. If someone has some documentation please share!

Answer (score -2):

You can use "`MARK:` " keyword for the comments.

For example:

```
//MARK: Height constant

let height = heightSlider.value
```